# Two prepositions side by side

Tags: prepositions, word-order, phrasal-verbs

From this sentence, I am not quite sure why are these two prepositions "on" and "in" used. **And,** can we **swap** the word further with on to be the second sentence?

> If we look further **on in** time, to the year 2737 BC, we arrive at the discovery of tea by a Chinese emperor.
>
> If we look **on further in** time, to the year 2737 BC, we arrive at the discovery of tea by a Chinese emperor.

Comment: In "further on in time" the word "on" is an adverb, not a preposition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Swapping changes the meaning.

**Further on in time**, means looking at a time that is further from the present (than a previously referenced time).

**Looked on further in time** - one wouldn't use that because "look on" has a different idiomatic meaning.

You could, however, say something like "Kept looking further back in time.." to mean that one continued looking (if it had already been stated that one had been looking at another period already).